# Html.Raw outputting HTML as text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a property in my Model which has `string` content similar to:

```
&lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;`
```

Using `@Html.Raw(myProperty)` outputs to the browser

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

When I expect

```
Hello
```

I tried doing `@Html.Raw(Html.Raw(myProperty))` but this reverted it back to the orginal string.

Is there any way to render this text as expected without resorting to using `.Replace("&lt;", "<")`, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myProperty))
```

Comment: It happens when brain and hands are not properly connected! :)